# libc++: Why is the stream still good after closing

Tags: c++, clang, libc++

I have a very simple program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void CHECK(std::iostream& s)
{
    std::cout << "good(): "  << s.good()
              << " fail(): " << s.fail()
              << " bad(): "  << s.bad()
              << " eof(): "  << s.eof() << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::fstream ofs("test.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
    std::cout << "opened" << std::endl;
    CHECK(ofs);
    ofs << "Hello, World!\n";
    CHECK(ofs);
    ofs.close();
    std::cout << "closed" << std::endl;
    CHECK(ofs);
    ofs << "Hello, World!\n";
    std::cout << "after operation" << std::endl;
    CHECK(ofs);
    return 0;
}
```

With `libc++` I get the following last line:

```
good(): 1 fail(): 0 bad(): 0 eof(): 0
```

Expected (or with `libstdc++`):

```
good(): 0 fail(): 1 bad(): 1 eof(): 0
```

I have tested on OSX with Xcode 9.4.1 (or on Linux), but always the same. Can anybody explain me the situation here? Also the file content was not updated, because already closed. Why is the stream still *good* after closing and further operation?

Comment: Probably a bug? Post on the libc++ list

Comment: You can file a bug against libc++ at https://bugs.llvm.org

Comment: Okay, thanks - I have created a [ticket](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38052)

Answer (score 1):

What I suspect is happening is that the operations are stuffing the data into the `rdbuf` associated with the stream. That succeeds, as long as there is room in the buffer. Eventually, the buffer gets full, and the stream attempts to write to the file (which is closed) and that fails.

You can test that by making the last bit a loop:

```
ofs.close();
std::cout << "closed" << std::endl;
CHECK(ofs);
for (int i = 0; i < 500; ++i)
    {
    ofs << "Hello, World!\n";
    std::cout << i << " ";
    CHECK(ofs);
    }
std::cout << "after operation" << std::endl;
```

On my machine, it fails after about 300 - and forever after that.
Is this correct behavior? (or even standards-compliant?)
I don't know.

[ Later: If I change libc++ do set the buffer size to 0 upon close, then the first write fails - so that suggests that my analysis is correct. However, I still haven't found anything in the standard about what this 'should' do. ]

Comment: About standard conformance, I suspect that pretty much anything done on a streambuf after closing it is undefined behavior.

Comment: Probably - but I'll have to research it to be sure.

Comment: The explanation in your first paragraph doesn't make much sense; closing a file should flush anything that is buffered

Comment: Right, but after that, ....  After the flush happens the buffer is empty. writing to it should be fine, until it's time to write it to the file.